# How are symmetric functions related to the proof of the Abel-Ruffini theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Good afternoon. I don't speak English. Therefore, there may be errors in the text. I found a proof of the Abel-Ruffini theorem, without using the Galois theory. This is the original proof, translated into modern mathematical language with minor changes. Link to it: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Rosen.pdf

I don't understand some features

1. Section 5 proves that the first radical in a radical chain of extensions must be square. I don’t understand where the transposition and the square radical have to do with it.
2. Why the radical expression of the square radical must necessarily have the form that is defined in section 3

Please explain without Galois theory